# When renting a car, is it a problem when a signature differs between the passport and license?

Tags: usa, passports, car-rentals, driving-licenses

I changed my signature a few years ago and as my current passport is issued years after my driving license the signatures are different.
All other details are exactly the same.

Will this pose a problem when renting a car in the US?

When signing contracts in Europe I have never seen anyone actually compare my signature with the one in the official document (passport/ID/license).
Additionally I am still able to write the old signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that this would cause a problem. The reason the car rental company would want to see your passport is that it's picture identification. When you sign the rental agreement, the fact that you're standing there is sufficient for them. The fact that the signature doesn't "match" is not relevant.

If things were to ever get to the point where you were asked in a court of law whether you signed a particular document or not, it's either a "yes" or "no" answer no matter what the signature actually looks like.